# How to reach the input file using java program < "filename"?

Tags: java, file-io, input, command-line, arguments

I'm doing an assignment where I'm supposed to work with a file. The tester uses the command argument

> "java puzzle < sample_input_1.txt"

to run the file with my program. My program being "puzzle" and the file being "sample_input_1.txt".

I've been searching a bit, but i'm not quite sure how to retrieve the data from this file. I'm used to getting the filepath as an argument to main, which I use a scanner to read.

How do I access this file when programming and retrieving it's data? I would like to do something like what a scanner does to read it.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on your standard input stream. To clarify, if you're used to using Scanner's constructor that accepts a File (like this):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

then use the Scanner's constructor that accepts an InputStream, and pass System.in:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You should be able to use the scanner in the same manner you're accustomed to after that.

Answer (score 0):

It comes to you in the stdin stream ( System.in ). The `< sample_input_1.txt` at the end of the command redirects the stdin stream to the given file. It's present in almost every terminal program. More information can be found [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way you can do is using **InputStream**:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String word;
    do {
    word = br.readLine();
    if (word != null) {
        list.add(word); //if you want add the file content to an ArrayList
    } else {
        return; //case file is empty, program is finished
    }
    } while (word != null);

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
}
```